# Why does a console window flash when I run my C++ program if default terminal application is "Windows Terminal"?

Tags: c++, console-application, codeblocks, windows-terminal

As you know, "Windows Terminal" application is exist in Windows 11.

Here is a screenshot from that application:

[image]

And here my source codes of my C++ program:

```
#include <clipboardxx.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string_operations.h>
using namespace clipboardxx;
using namespace std;

///--- Değişkenler ---///
//clipboard
clipboard clpPano;

//string
string strOgeninKonumu;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if(argc == 2)
    {
        strOgeninKonumu  = string(argv[1]);

        ReplaceString(strOgeninKonumu, "\\", "\\\\", 0, strOgeninKonumu);

        strOgeninKonumu = "\"" + strOgeninKonumu + "\"";

        clpPano << strOgeninKonumu;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I use Code::Blocks as IDE.

I set the application type to "GUI application" in order to create hidden console application.

If I choose "Windows Console Host" option, my program does not flash.

But if I choose "Windows Terminal" option, my program flashes.

How do I create %100 hidden C++ program and prevent flashing in Code::Blocks?

Comment: Probably because it opens a terminal (as you have configured), runs your application, then quits?

Comment: There is no point in asking for a terminal when your program never uses it.  The IDE could be a little smarter about this, using the same test that the OS uses.  Consider to file a bug with the project.